# Basic auth and jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, basic-authentication

I have two systems - one that's an API that just returns data from a database, and another which displays said data.

Both systems live on different urls, are written in node.js + express, and use helmet.

I've api works correctly, and implements basic auth. I've used swagger to test it, and everything seems perfect.

I've written the system that makes an AJAX call to the api and returns data.

```
const makeRequest = function () {
  const request = $.ajax({
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ${hash of the username:password}',
    },
    // crossDomain: true,  - thanks Kaddath! 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    url: `${url}`,
  });

  ...
```

The AJAX call results in a 401 error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

5a3ce14cbf309e6a92ee6216:1 Failed to load #request-url#: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

scripts.js:144 error
```

The system doesn't work either locally - or when on live.

**When the end point is hit the `req.headers.authorization` param is `empty` - not even failing.**

The system works flawlessly if I remove the basic auth requirement on the endpoint - so it's literally just that.

I've seen quite a few ways of implementing basic auth in an AJAX request, but none seem to be working - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Ollie

Comment: Given the error it seems most likely that the result of your hashing algorithm for the `username:password` in JS isn't matching the output the server expects

Comment: Also note that 'url: `${url}`' can just be changed to `url: url`

Comment: NOTE: `crossDomain: true,` doesn't allow requests to be cross-domain, it is used to force the request to be considered cross-domain even if executed on the same domain. (just in case there was a confusion, this one happens often)

Comment: @Kaddath - looks like I fell for that trap - thanks for that :)

Comment: @Kaddath - I replaced the url in the message, as I'm a little cautious around that sort of thing - I'll make that more clear. Thanks + Sorry!